# simplexml + foreach +twitter with unexpected results

Tags: php, simplexml

Im using the following code to output all the  nodes from the xml shown.

```
        $cursor = "?cursor=-1"
        $xml= new SimpleXmlElement($to->OAuthRequest('http://twitter.com/statuses/followers.xml?$cursor'));
        foreach ($xml->xpath('/users_list/users/user') as $user) {
            $id = $user->id;
            $names .= $user->screen_name;
            $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
        }
        $next = $user->next_link;
        $prev = $user->prev_link;
        $pusharray = array("$names", "$next", "$prev");
```

All i get back is `Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )`

Heres a sample of the xml
http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barakobama.xml?cursor=-1

What am i doing wrong? Everything everyone has suggested has not worked! Im going insane.

Comment: @gumbo http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barakobama.xml?cursor=-1

Comment: @Patrick: So `$to->OAuthRequest` doesn’t return the expected XML code? Ah, by the way: variables in single quotes are not expanded. So `'…$cursor'` will be `'…$cursor'` and not `'…'` concatenated with the contents of `$cursor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need either:

```
$id = $user['id'];
```

or

```
$id = $user->attributes()->id;
```

See [basic usage of SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). What you're doing isn't a valid way of querying an attribute.

Comment: It returns nothing because there is _no_ "id" attribute in the source XML. No idea why you accepted that answer, seems random.

Comment: Because it addresses the problem: querying attributes the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$users_list = simplexml_load_file('http://twitter.com/statuses/followers/barakobama.xml?cursor=-1');

foreach ($users_list->users->user as $user)
{
    echo $user->id, ' ', $user->screen_name, ' ', $user->profile_image_url, "<br />\n";
}

echo 'prev: ', $users_list->previous_cursor, ' - next: ', $users_list->next_cursor;
```

There is no `next_link` or `prev_link` in that XML, I assume you're talking about `previous_cursor` and `next_cursor`